# Null Pointing when adding to a fragment's layout

Tags: android

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when trying to add a `textView` programmatically to a fragment.

I think the context is coming back null but I could be wrong.  The crash is happening at `startMenu.addView(tv);`

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

View inflatedView;
Context context = null;
private Bundle mBundle;
private LinearLayout startMenull ;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }

    if (inflatedView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) inflatedView.getParent();


        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(inflatedView);
    }
    try {

        inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_menu, container,
                false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        //startMenu = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_menull);
        startMenu = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater(mBundle).inflate(R.id.start_menull, null);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setId(1);
        tv.setText("Here is the text Box");    
        startMenu.addView(tv);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }
    return inflatedView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    mBundle = savedInstanceState;
}
```

}

Updated above code 9/16 3:48

Solved:
 in the try/catch

```
inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_menu, container,
                false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        startMenull =((LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.start_menull));
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setId(1);
        tv.setText("Here is the text Box");    
        startMenull.addView(tv);
```

Comment: That means `startMenu` is null. Are you inflating it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line.  Debug your app.  Inspect `startMenu` and `context` in the variables window. What values do they have?

Comment: @ 323go  All the code is above.  I tried startMenu = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater(mBundle).inflate(R.id.start_menu2, null); as well with no luck   by adding mBundle = savedInstanceState to the onCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

context cant be null at that point, since he is using applicationContext.

but start Menu IS! null since onCreate is called before onCreateView. So you would have to inflate the View first, which you should do in onCreateView not onCreate.

Just Noticed you are inflating the View in onCreateView, but still you cant Access it in onCreate as it is called before onCreateView.

See Android Life Cycle. http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

View inflatedView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_menu, container,false);

    LinearLayout startMenu = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.start_menu);
    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setId(1);
    tv.setText("Here is the text view");    
    startMenu.addView(tv);

    return inflatedView;
 }
}
```

If i wanted to do something like you are doing, this would b how i'd do it. Why would u check if container is null? or why would you assume that inflatedView is != null?

Comment: Even if I move the code into the try/catch in the onCreateView() I have no luck. I did try (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater(mBundle).inflate(R.id.start_menu, null);   but it says no resource found exception when ran in the onCreateView().

Comment: haha Just figured it out and went to update the code and saw you came up with the same thing  Thanks!

Comment: To answer your questions of why check nulls.  Just for playing and learning curve sake.  We have different layouts, and in one of them this fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment may still be created from its saved state, but there is no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could just run the code below, where we would create and return the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.

Answer (score -1):

onCreate calls before onCreateView. Read about lifecycle.